# DefaultIfEmpty returning null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am working with `C#`, `.NET4.5`, `EF6`(shouldn't matter really).

I am selecting some values from db then `.ToList()` them and then adding `DefaultIfEmpty(new ActualFee{Net = 0, Vat = 0})` if one does not exist, and I get `null`

```
public static ConveyancingSummaryVm ToConveyancingSummaryVm(this Tuple<IEnumerable<ActualFee>, ConveyancingAnswer, Customer> conveyancePricingAnswersAndCustomer)
        {
            var purchaseFees = conveyancePricingAnswersAndCustomer.Item1.Where(o => o.ConveyancingSaleType == "Purchase").ToList();

            if (purchaseFees.Any())
            {
                var discount = purchaseFees.DefaultIfEmpty(new ActualFee{Net = 0, Vat = 0}).SingleOrDefault(o => o.Title.Contains("Discount")); 

                conveyancingSummaryVm.IsPurchaseFreehold = conveyancePricingAnswersAndCustomer.Item2.PropertyBoughtIsFreehold;
...
```

[image]

I must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: most likely SingleOrDefault is returning null.

Comment: See above comment - but also, why use DefaultIfEmpty in conjunction with Any() - presumably it can't be empty, if you've got 'Some'.

Comment: @Selman22 so you are saying that `DefaultIfEmpty` does not work for  `SingleOrDefault` ?

Comment: Your question actually has a lot of sense, as the method suggest "If empty then return this default value"... I don;t understand why SingleOrDEFAULT is not retrieving what you are suggesting as DEFAULT. Probably your scenario would work if your list is EMPTY (not null), as in Count=0... in that case I think it will return your default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way for `DefaultIfEmpty` to return null in this case. When there is no element it returns an `ActualFee` instance and the `Title` does not contain `Discount`. So that's why `SingleOrDefault` returns `null`.

> so you are saying that DefaultIfEmpty does not work for SingleOrDefault?

No, `DefaultIfEmpty` works and returns the expected value. And then `SingleOrDefault` runs on the return value of `DefaultIfEmpty` and returns *null* because there is no element in the sequence that satisfies your condition.

You can use null coalescing operator to get the behaviour you want:

```
var discount = purchaseFees.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Title.Contains("Discount")) 
              ?? new ActualFee{Net = 0, Vat = 0};
```

Comment: So basically do this? `var discount = purchaseFees.Any(o => o.Title.Contains("Discount"))? purchaseFees.Single(o => o.Title.Contains("Discount")) : new ActualFee{Net = 0, Vat = 0};`

Comment: @Liufa I would prefer FirstOrDefault and there is no need for Any. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

`SingleOrDefault` must've returned `null`.  If `DefaultIfEmpty` had returned `null`, it would've returned a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.  Please rewrite that statement without chaining.

Answer (score 0):

OP here: Figured another workaround.

Rather than using `Single()` if you are willing to 'sacrifice' the check for it to be single record what you can do is use `Where()` and `Sum()` combo.

I know there's always one or zero Severances.

Example:

```
var feeValue = legalFees.Where(o => o.Title.Contains("Severance"));
premiumDetails.LegalFeeNet = feeValue.Sum(o => o.Net);
premiumDetails.LegalFeeVat = feeValue.Sum(o => o.Vat);
```

if there are no records this returns `0` for `Net` and `Vat` and if there is - returns the values.

**UPDATE - Figured another one:**

`legalFees.Where(o => o.Title.Contains("Severance")).Union(new ActualFee{Net = 0, Vat = 0}).First();`

if `Where()` does return something then `First()` will be the value that `Contains("Severance")`, if it does not - then `First()` will be whatever is in `Union()`.